# C++ : Pointer to "new Class()" function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have a `Parent` abstract class, and derivated `Foo` and `Bar` classes. They all have a constructor taking a `string name` parameter. They have a string type() member function which returns "foo" and "bar" respectively.

Now I would like to build a dictionnary with keys "foo" and "bar", and values equal to pointers to functions creating a new instance of the corresponding class. This means these pointers will be of type `Parent* (*) (const string &)` and executing them will be equivalent to calling `new Foo(name)` and `new Bar(name)`

Can I avoid creating a static function for each class that will just call new, and get a pointer to this static function?

Thanks!

Edit : Actually, the goal behind this is implementing a plugin system in my app, the plugins adding new Derived class types. The plugin authors are generally my customers, and for this reason, I want to let them the most simple and elegant interface possible. So declaring and registering the factory functions should be as simple and as short as possible for them

Comment: You can avoid creating a static function by creating a non-static function.

Comment: @juabchopanza : huh? this is an allocator function, so it's not supposed to work on a class instance (as opposed to a clone function)... out of topic

Comment: Exactly, and I am not saying it should work on a class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a factory function for each class you want to be able to build by this means. The following code shows you how to do so without having to recur to static members and by not writing by hand a number of different functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct Parent{
    Parent(std::string){}
};

struct Child1 : public Parent{
    Child1(std::string d) : Parent(d){
        std::cout << "Child1 constructor: " << d << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Child2 : public Parent{
    Child2(std::string d) : Parent(d){
        std::cout << "Child2 constructor: " << d << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename Product, typename Return, typename Parameter>
Return factory(const Parameter& a){
    return Return(new Product(a));
}

std::map<std::string, std::function<Parent*(std::string)> > mrp;
std::map<std::string, std::function<std::shared_ptr<Parent>(std::string)> > msp;

int main(){
    mrp["Child1"] = &factory<Child1, Parent*, std::string>;
    mrp["Child2"] = &factory<Child2, Parent*, std::string>;

    Parent* a = mrp["Child1"]("one");
    delete a;
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> b(mrp["Child2"]("two"));


    msp["Child1"] = &factory<Child1, std::shared_ptr<Parent>, std::string>;
    msp["Child2"] = &factory<Child2, std::shared_ptr<Parent>, std::string>;

    msp["Child1"]("one");
    msp["Child2"]("two");
}
```

try this code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=24a83fec04f4dd142cd92651490ea9c0-105ac1d5bf768d76df90c5569141bd7f).
Also, as you can see, this method can be "configured" to use std::shared_ptr, raw pointers, ... and with different ownership semanthics, notice the line:

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> b(mrp["Child2"]("two"));
```

However, any variation of what you briefly described in the question is, well, a variation of it! What you are trying to do is an abstract factory, which "standard" implementation relies exactly on making a factory function for each class you want to build. As I said, it doesn't need to be a static member of the class, it can well be a non-member non-friend function but this doesn't change very much (except better encapsulation, and the need for the constructor being public, or for the factory to be friend, which, somehow, breaks encapsulation).

The object factory is implemented in a very elegant way in [loki](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/Factory.h?view=markup). Refer to Modern C++ (Alexandrescu) for a thorough discussion of the design pattern itself as well as of the implementation given by loki.

As for your edit: registration in loki is sweet and simple as in (cited from the book):

```
// Implementation module for class Line 
// Create an anonymous namespace 
// to make the function invisible from other modules 
namespace 
{ 
 Shape* CreateLine() 
 { 
 return new Line; 
 } 
 // The ID of class Line 
 const int LINE = 1; 
 // Assume TheShapeFactory is a singleton factory 
 // (see Chapter 6) 
 const bool registered = 
 TheShapeFactory::Instance().RegisterShape( 
 LINE, CreateLine); 
}
```

Comment: @DyP actually, you can easily satisfy the requirement by writing a *non-static* function for each class :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza But this requires that you can create dummy instances from the class for the dictionary. This might be difficult considering class invariants, const members, ref members, RAII etc.. right?

Comment: @DyP Why can't you just create an object and return it? Anyway, I wasn't suggesting doing that, just pointing out that the requirements are confused.

Comment: @juanchopanza If it's a non-static member function, you need to have an instance to call it. The question is about creating instances of classes from string keys for the classes (-> dictionary), so you would need to associate the string key to a (dummy) instance of the class with a member function that creates new instances. Or did I simply misunderstand you?

Comment: @DyP can you show me how you would use CRTP for this? It would be interesting to me. You can post the code on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ Thanks

Comment: @DyP I never said anything about member functions. I am not convinced it is necessary to associate the string key to a dummy instance of the class. If this were the case, then some static instances could do.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok, non-static vs non-member ... i.e. I *did* misunderstand you :)

Comment: @DyP non-static *and* non-member :-)

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Something along the lines of [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1de043571a2217585def100d626025eb-c59112800dca6ae4674520521ddfe536).

Comment: @galinette , is this what you needed?

Comment: @dyp I see. That's similar to what I did some time ago (I was tired of always writing factory functions) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=80e6387fd35036e2e970f32d9593ebce-105ac1d5bf768d76df90c5569141bd7f

Comment: @Dyp Thank you very much (I forgot in the previous comment :) )

Comment: @StefanoFalasca No problem, it's also rather pointless. I thought you could combine that with some magic using static data members, but they're only instantiated when required (implicit instantiation of the class template). You had to use a static data member in the derived type, and then you can as well use a non-member function to achieve the same magic, avoiding multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I must be quite tired for not having thought using a template... I did not know that this is called a factory, and this will allow far better googling.

Answer (score 8):

> Can I avoid creating a static function for each class that will just call new, and get a pointer to this static function?

Yes, you can create a generic function:

```
template <typename T>
ptr_type<Parent> create() {
    return new T();
}
```

… and then take its address (but you need to get an address *per derived type*).

Note that I have explicitly *not* used `T*` as a return type – raw pointers should never own memory … an appropriate smart pointer should instead be used here.

Comment: You indeed should use ptr_type<Parent>, otherwise you won't be able to put them in a dictionary.

Comment: I still can't see how you will add a pointer to a template function in a dictionary.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit `&create<Foo>` and `&create<Bar>`. Just like a pointer to any other function. (of course, they need the same return type)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: if its returns `Parent*` (or smart pointer if you're so inclined), you can certainly add them to a dictionary.. `std::map<std::string, Parent* (*)(std::string const&)> factories; factories["Foo"] = &create<Foo>;`

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit have a look here for how to add a pointer to a template function to, in my example, a vector http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=39f58560fd838a14e718d7b7de61eba4-105ac1d5bf768d76df90c5569141bd7f

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, @riv: thanks. Ok, so this answer will not work out of the box because `&create<Foo>` and `&create<Bar>` will have a different signature. I think the answer needs some improvement

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit the answer does mention using `ptr_type<Parent>` instead. I think it's fine.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Sigh. Fixed. I dislike the current answer though because it’s less generic (and making it generic again by making `Parent` a template argument makes it less usable). But I get the point about having to stuff it into a dictionary, of course.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: adding an additional 'Parent' template parameter is what is needed here IMO. Or the OP can use this as static template method inside the Parent class.

Comment: @Wouter Like I said, I could do that, but it would make the function directly less usable (you always have to specify that extra parameter) … and since its use is quite limited anyway (hey, it’s one expression – how generic does it need to be?) I opt not to do it ;)

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is a factory method pattern.
Here's a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern
The static function or a factory of some sort basically the thing you want.

Why do you want to avoid the static creation method?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the link. The actual code is more complex and is a plugin system, plugins adding new derived class types to the app. I'd like plugin authors having to write as less code as possible (they are customers...), with as much as possible already included in the headers.